# Animation in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I was looking for the logo to reduce to some default size from the actual size and after completion of that some text data should be shown....

but when i saw the facebook website there was no where i found reducing the size of the logo from default.

How should i achieve this

```
 Animated.timing(
this.spinValue,
{
  toValue: 1,
  duration: 4000,
  easing: Easing.linear
}
```

i didn't get how to change the size of the image in this...

Along with decreasing the size of the image i want the image to move top so some space left at the bottom there i would like to show other text on completion of the animation...

Sorry if i'm wrong..help me out with some docs or references

I have tried:

```
const imagePos = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [500, 200]
    })
    const imageTop = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [400, 100]
      })

  return <View>
  <Animated.Image style={{ height:imagePos ,width:imagePos ,top : imageTop }} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('../assets/new_images/logo1.png')} />

  </View>
```

Comment: define a height and width for your message and set it as a state. Then change your height/width state in Animation. If this doesnt help I can write an example perhaps.

Comment: @abeikverdi can you help me out with an example. I was not able to achieve....i have updated my  codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by using multiple animations

this is my componentdidmount

```
Animated.timing(
        this.state.scaleValue,
        {toValue: 1 ,duration : 1000 ,easing : Easing.ease ,delay:0}
      ).start();
```

this is my rendet

```
   const imagePos = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [200, 150]
    })
    const imageTop = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0.35*windowHeight, 0.1*windowHeight]
      })
      const content = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0.6*windowHeight, 0]
        })

  return <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center'}}>
  <Animated.Image style={{ height:imagePos ,width:imagePos ,top :imageTop}} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('../assets/new_images/main_screen.png')} />
  <Animated.View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',top : content}}>

    <View><Text>Hi this is bottom content</Text></View>
    </Animated.View>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use "scale" to scale down image size on componentDidMount. If I understood you correctly this is what you want

```
class Playground extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scaleValue: new Animated.Value(1),
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.spring(                          
      this.state.scaleValue,                 
      {toValue: 0.5}
    ).start();                                
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.Image                         
        source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/XMKOH81.jpg'}}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          transform: [                        
            {scale: this.state.scaleValue},  
          ]
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? Or can you explain in more detail or show video of what you want to animate? :D

Comment: I got it worked.....firstly logo should decrease size and also should move up and parallely bottom contents(initially bottom contents should not visible) comes up.....thats what i was requierd......

Comment: Maybe you should post your answer here so everyone who comes by can see it? :D